# Spring MVC: point to JSP in separate project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

I'm attempting to do something and I'm not sure if it's even the best way to do.

Basically I have two projects, one is a web application and the other is a project that plugs into the web app. The plugin project has a JSP file that I wanted to have it accessible through the web.

Here's what I tried in the web context configuration without success:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login.jsp" view-name="classpath:/com/my/plugin/login.jsp" />
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? does it even make sense to do it this way?

Thanks a log

Comment: When you say "separate project", I assume you mean a different WAR deployed on the same application server.  If so, I think the only way is to do a `foward:<fullpath>`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. The separate project is actually a JAR, not another deployed web app. so I have one deployed WAR that includes this plugin JAR with the JSP in it. does that make more sense?

Comment: What error are you getting?  As long as your JSP is in that classpath it should work.  Note: Your path is set to `/login.jsp`, so you will have to use the URL http://<hostname>:<port>/<context>/login.jsp

Comment: When I access https://localhost:8443/login.jsp, I get a "404 Problem accessing /login.jsp. Reason: NOT_FOUND". Isn't there a way to point to that outer JSP without having to specify the context? just like as if the JSP was in the app's WEB-INF directory.

Comment: You can deploy in embedded tomcat or embedded jetty (or some other app server that allows "embedded" mode, like Glassfish???).  Otherwise I don't think it's possible since the system has to be able to differentiate between the deployments.